# Dismiss Keyboard Number Pad

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I would like to dismiss my number pad, when the user presses the background. My issue is I cannot find a text field to call ResignFirstResponder. I am using MonoTouch.Dialog. Because I can override InputAccessoryView, here is my code:

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.Dialog;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Drawing;

namespace MyApp
{
public class JMADialogViewController : DialogViewController
{
    public JMADialogViewController (RootElement root, bool pushing) : base(UITableViewStyle.Grouped, root, pushing)
    {
    }

    UIView dismiss;

    public override UIView InputAccessoryView 
    {
        get 
        {
            if (dismiss == null)
            {
                dismiss = new UIView(new RectangleF(0,0,320,27));         
                dismiss.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
                UIButton dismissBtn = new UIButton(new RectangleF(255, 2, 58, 23));
                dismissBtn.SetTitle("Done", UIControlState.Normal);      
                dismissBtn.TouchDown += delegate {
                    //textField.ResignFirstResponder();
                    dismiss.ResignFirstResponder();
                };
                dismiss.AddSubview(dismissBtn);
            }
            return dismiss;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why is this tagged as ios when it's java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dismiss the keyboard in any view that has the focused textview under it with EndEditing(), so probably adding this would work:

```
        this.View.EndEditing(true);
```

Comment: Thanks! Here is my final code: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/3810#Comment_3810

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a button with no background and at front put all the textfields. So any place that the user touch will hide the keyboard.
Link the button with a inaction with this code:

[self.view endEditing:YES];

This is the solution that i use in my apps. Hope result helpful!